# How can I map data from json file in recat native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to fish data with images but how can I do two map inside each othe I need only the first image from every item

here is the JSON file
`

```
"items": Array [
      Object {
        "external_urls": Object {
          "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/5staYrHq4jR1NiBfRR2XWr",
        },
        "followers": Object {
          "href": null,
          "total": 433,
        },
        "genres": Array [],
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/5staYrHq4jR1NiBfRR2XWr",
        "id": "5staYrHq4jR1NiBfRR2XWr",
        "images": Array [
          Object {
            "height": 640,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000e5eb038f9071ec89962e7ad16b77",
            "width": 640,
          },
          Object {
            "height": 320,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616100005174038f9071ec89962e7ad16b77",
            "width": 320,
          },
          Object {
            "height": 160,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000f178038f9071ec89962e7ad16b77",
            "width": 160,
          },
        ],
        "name": "DOXX",
        "popularity": 6,
        "type": "artist",
        "uri": "spotify:artist:5staYrHq4jR1NiBfRR2XWr",
      },
      Object {
        "external_urls": Object {
          "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/1MVFEpYdHtdV3k8Bgs79Pl",
        },
        "followers": Object {
          "href": null,
          "total": 404,
        },
        "genres": Array [],
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1MVFEpYdHtdV3k8Bgs79Pl",
        "id": "1MVFEpYdHtdV3k8Bgs79Pl",
        "images": Array [
          Object {
            "height": 640,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000e5ebd1578a57ff89ac9aeed23863",
            "width": 640,
          },
          Object {
            "height": 320,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616100005174d1578a57ff89ac9aeed23863",
            "width": 320,
          },
          Object {
            "height": 160,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000f178d1578a57ff89ac9aeed23863",
            "width": 160,
          },
        ],
        "name": "DOXY",
        "popularity": 14,
        "type": "artist",
        "uri": "spotify:artist:1MVFEpYdHtdV3k8Bgs79Pl",
      },
      Object {
        "external_urls": Object {
          "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/1HliyC4gHWRHHFy3CjR3Bp",
        },
        "followers": Object {
          "href": null,
          "total": 2,
        },
        "genres": Array [],
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1HliyC4gHWRHHFy3CjR3Bp",
        "id": "1HliyC4gHWRHHFy3CjR3Bp",
        "images": Array [],
        "name": "Doxy601",
        "popularity": 5,
        "type": "artist",
        "uri": "spotify:artist:1HliyC4gHWRHHFy3CjR3Bp",
      },
      Object {
        "external_urls": Object {
          "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/7d8a8D8ZfVdYsuAcMk4Kxy",
        },
        "followers": Object {
          "href": null,
          "total": 97,
        },
        "genres": Array [],
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/7d8a8D8ZfVdYsuAcMk4Kxy",
        "id": "7d8a8D8ZfVdYsuAcMk4Kxy",
        "images": Array [
          Object {
            "height": 640,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b2736862f6dfd64d0c65d70c4623",
            "width": 640,
          },
          Object {
            "height": 300,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e026862f6dfd64d0c65d70c4623",
            "width": 300,
          },
          Object {
            "height": 64,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d000048516862f6dfd64d0c65d70c4623",
            "width": 64,
          },
        ],
        "name": "Miles Davis & Milt Jackson",
        "popularity": 5,
        "type": "artist",
        "uri": "spotify:artist:7d8a8D8ZfVdYsuAcMk4Kxy",
      },
      Object {
        "external_urls": Object {
          "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/6NrhhuvYUPDmZ7RiZAWQih",
        },
        "followers": Object {
          "href": null,
          "total": 546,
        },
        "genres": Array [],
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6NrhhuvYUPDmZ7RiZAWQih",
        "id": "6NrhhuvYUPDmZ7RiZAWQih",
        "images": Array [
          Object {
            "height": 640,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000e5ebe2cae73d43e39e83aebc2bf5",
            "width": 640,
          },
          Object {
            "height": 320,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616100005174e2cae73d43e39e83aebc2bf5",
            "width": 320,
          },
          Object {
            "height": 160,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000f178e2cae73d43e39e83aebc2bf5",
            "width": 160,
          },
        ],
        "name": "DOX",
        "popularity": 25,
        "type": "artist",
        "uri": "spotify:artist:6NrhhuvYUPDmZ7RiZAWQih",
      },
      Object {
        "external_urls": Object {
          "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/6792Ts7YzD8dhGkgSHPNEL",
        },
        "followers": Object {
          "href": null,
          "total": 125,
        },
        "genres": Array [],
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6792Ts7YzD8dhGkgSHPNEL",
        "id": "6792Ts7YzD8dhGkgSHPNEL",
        "images": Array [
          Object {
            "height": 640,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273e2318a139e0f022870baac23",
            "width": 640,
          },
          Object {
            "height": 300,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02e2318a139e0f022870baac23",
            "width": 300,
          },
          Object {
            "height": 64,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00004851e2318a139e0f022870baac23",
            "width": 64,
          },
        ],
        "name": "Miles Davis And Milt Jackson Sextet",
        "popularity": 1,
        "type": "artist",
        "uri": "spotify:artist:6792Ts7YzD8dhGkgSHPNEL",
      },
      Object {
        "external_urls": Object {
          "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/2b69LpXVfEagXEJpHjj3vW",
        },
        "followers": Object {
          "href": null,
          "total": 10,
        },
        "genres": Array [],
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/2b69LpXVfEagXEJpHjj3vW",
        "id": "2b69LpXVfEagXEJpHjj3vW",
        "images": Array [
          Object {
            "height": 640,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000e5eb634c7182d6152094085cf475",
            "width": 640,
          },
          Object {
            "height": 320,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616100005174634c7182d6152094085cf475",
            "width": 320,
          },
          Object {
            "height": 160,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000f178634c7182d6152094085cf475",
            "width": 160,
          },
        ],
        "name": "XODUS MMXXI",
        "popularity": 12,
        "type": "artist",
        "uri": "spotify:artist:2b69LpXVfEagXEJpHjj3vW",
      },
      Object {
        "external_urls": Object {
          "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/1IhDCe20UkuG9o00cnhvS8",
        },
        "followers": Object {
          "href": null,
          "total": 106,
        },
        "genres": Array [],
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1IhDCe20UkuG9o00cnhvS8",
        "id": "1IhDCe20UkuG9o00cnhvS8",
        "images": Array [
          Object {
            "height": 640,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273802c20b22f713bf4ca551ea9",
            "width": 640,
          },
          Object {
            "height": 300,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02802c20b22f713bf4ca551ea9",
            "width": 300,
          },
          Object {
            "height": 64,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00004851802c20b22f713bf4ca551ea9",
            "width": 64,
          },
        ],
        "name": "Doxi",
        "popularity": 11,
        "type": "artist",
        "uri": "spotify:artist:1IhDCe20UkuG9o00cnhvS8",
      },
      Object {
        "external_urls": Object {
          "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/0joBZjd7WSxAGlRC2pvaJM",
        },
        "followers": Object {
          "href": null,
          "total": 0,
        },
        "genres": Array [],
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0joBZjd7WSxAGlRC2pvaJM",
        "id": "0joBZjd7WSxAGlRC2pvaJM",
        "images": Array [
          Object {
            "height": 640,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27375b17d2e3f94ae1bddd65046",
            "width": 640,
          },
          Object {
            "height": 300,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e0275b17d2e3f94ae1bddd65046",
            "width": 300,
          },
          Object {
            "height": 64,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000485175b17d2e3f94ae1bddd65046",
            "width": 64,
          },
        ],
        "name": "Prod.Dozy",
        "popularity": 1,
        "type": "artist",
        "uri": "spotify:artist:0joBZjd7WSxAGlRC2pvaJM",
      },
```

`

I did this to map data {items.map((data,i)=>({data.name}))}
I do this and it works but I want also to get the first image for each item can I do two maps inside each other ??

but how I can get these data with the first image for every item

Comment: You need the name and first image of each object? Show some code of what you already have set up.

Comment: yes, that's right ,I added my code

Answer (score 0):

You can load multiple items from an array using just one map.
To get the first image of every item you'll have to access the first item from the image array `[0]` and from that image you'll need the url to fill the `source` property of an `<Image/>` component (from React Native). You'll also need to supply the width and height to the style property like so:

```
{items.map((data) => ( <> 
        <Image style={{width: `${data.images[0].width}`, height: `${data.images[0].height}` }} source={require(`${data.images[0].url}`)}/>
        <div>{data.name}</div> </>))}
```

I also wrapped `Image` and `div` in a React fragment: `<></>`

Comment: I tired this but it gives an error : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.images[0].url')

Comment: @sam Looking at the example data you provided, for some of the items, the `images` array is empty. You will need to perform a check to make sure that the `data.images` is not empty before trying to access it.

Comment: As @Andrew said, you'll need to make sure to handle the images when they're empty. You can easily do that by adding `?` like this:  `data.images[0]?.width`